# Error with if/else condition in main method

Tags: c#

I need to press <kbd>t</kbd> two times in order to get any output; otherwise the program goes directly into the else condition or gives an exception handler error. What am I doing wrong here?

As you guys can see there are two classes one `twotable` and other `program` which contains the main method. I am trying to get the output using the invoke method of `twotable` class.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{               
    class twotable        
    {        
        public static void two()
        {
            int i;
            int j;
            for (i = 1; i <= 10;i++)
            {
                for (j = 2; j <= 2;j++ )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i * j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press t for two table");
            char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            {
                char t = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                if (c == t)
                {

                    twotable.two();
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("i hate u");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ReadKey to read a character http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from the console twice.

Instead of

```
char t = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
if (c == t)
```

You need

```
if (c == 't')
```

Comment: @james thanks that really helped i was not using the quotation for t . totally forgot it i am new :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the user to enter in the character 't' twice on separate ReadLine()s in order to show the output?  If so:

```
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Press t for two table");
        char c1 = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        char c2 = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        if (c1 == 't' && c2 == 't')
        {
            twotable.two();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i hate u");
        }
    }
```

Or do you want to read in 'tt' in one ReadLine()?

```
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Press t for two table");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input.Equals("tt"))
        {
            twotable.two();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i hate u");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here - `char c`.  You're comparing `char c`  with `char t`

Both lines ask for user input.

`char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 0):

Code is little bit messy, but loking even on *this* code

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
...
{
    char t = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
.....
}
```

you call `Console.ReadLine(...)` 2 times, so you need to press `t` 2 times. 
It's hard to say, but **probabbly** you want to do something like:

```
char t = 't';
...
{
    char consoleChar = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    if(consoleChar == t) // or simple if(consoleChar == 't')
    {
       //do something here, we get a t symbol from console
    }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My be need to use [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey) instead, and test `c == 't'`:

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user.

and your code like this:

```
var cki = Console.ReadKey();
if (cki.KeyChar == 't')
{
    ...
}
```